# How to seek MediaPlayerElement through C#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I am creating a CustomMediaTransportControls for `MediaPlayerElement`. In it, I have added a new button to Create a window with the currently playing video in [CompactOverlay Mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/universal-windows-app-model/2017/02/11/compactoverlay-mode-aka-picture-in-picture/). I have done it using below code.

```
//Button click event for CompactOverlayButton to Create a Frame in CompactOverlay mode
public async void CompactOverlayButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int compactViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;      //Initializing compactViewId to the Current View ID
    await CoreApplication.CreateNewView().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        var frame = new Frame();
        compactViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        frame.Navigate(typeof(VideoPlayerPage));
        Window.Current.Content = frame;
        Window.Current.Activate();
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = "";
    });
    bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsViewModeAsync(compactViewId, ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
    compactOverlayButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

But one problem is I want to resume the video from the point where the user clicks CompactOverlay button. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one possible solution for your problem is using [Navigate(TypeName, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Frame_Navigate_Windows_UI_Xaml_Interop_TypeName_System_Object_) method to pass the current playback position to your `VideoPlayerPage` and in `VideoPlayerPage` code-behind file, override the [OnNavigatedTo](http://Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Page_OnNavigatedTo_Windows_UI_Xaml_Navigation_NavigationEventArgs_) method to resume the video from current playback position.

For example, let's assume there are two `MediaPlayerElement` named "mediaPlayerElement" in current page and `VideoPlayerPage`. In current page, we can pass the current playback position to `pass the current playback position` like the following:

```
//Get current playback position
var position = mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.Position;

int compactViewId = 0;
await CoreApplication.CreateNewView().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    var frame = new Frame();
    compactViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    frame.Navigate(typeof(VideoPlayerPage), position);
    Window.Current.Content = frame;
    Window.Current.Activate();
    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = "";
});
bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsViewModeAsync(compactViewId, ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
```

However, `CompactOverlayButton_ClickAsync` is a function in `CustomMediaTransportControls` which is a derived class from [MediaTransportControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediatransportcontrols). Form here we can't get the `mediaPlayerElement`. So we need do some modifications here.

When adding a custom command button in custom transport controls, we usually will use a public `EventHandler` to perform the action that occurs when the button is clicked. For more info, please see **[Adding a custom button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls#adding-a-custom-button)** in [Create custom transport controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls).

In this case, we can add a `EventHandler` like:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> CompactOverlaid;
...
//Button click event for CompactOverlayButton to Create a Frame in CompactOverlay mode
public void CompactOverlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{               
    CompactOverlaid?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    compactOverlayButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

And in current page, use the `CustomMediaTransportControls` like:

```
<local:CustomMediaTransportControls x:Name="CustomMediaControl"  CompactOverlaid="CustomMediaControl_CompactOverlaid"/>
```

```
private async void CustomMediaControl_CompactOverlaid(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get current playback position
    var position = mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.Position;

    int compactViewId = 0;
    await CoreApplication.CreateNewView().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        var frame = new Frame();
        compactViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        frame.Navigate(typeof(VideoPlayerPage), position);
        Window.Current.Content = frame;
        Window.Current.Activate();
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = "";
    });
    bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsViewModeAsync(compactViewId, ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
}
```

And then in `VideoPlayerPage` code-behind file, override the [OnNavigatedTo](http://Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Page_OnNavigatedTo_Windows_UI_Xaml_Navigation_NavigationEventArgs_) method like the following:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    /// set media source
    ...
    /// set media source

    if (e.Parameter is TimeSpan position)
    {
        mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.Position = position;
    }

    mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

After this, the video should be able to play from the position where the user clicks `CompactOverlayButton`.

Comment: `CompactOverlayButton_ClickAsync` is a function in `CustomMediaTransportControls` which is a derived class from `MediaTransportControls`. It is not the function behind the Code of the Current Page. So how do I use it? I hope you understand.

Comment: @VijayNirmal Didn't note your `CompactOverlayButton_ClickAsync` is in your `CustomMediaTransportControls`. I've updated my answer, please have a check.